# struts2 annotation spring managed beans

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, struts2, annotations, spring-annotations

I'm using Spring to manage the struts 2 action beans. I am trying to migrate from XML based configuration to annotation based. I am using the struts2-spring-plugin so that struts gets the handle to the object managed by spring.
The following is in the applicationContext file for myAction.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema
      /beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org
      /schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean id="myAction123" class="com.action.MyAction" scope="prototype"></bean>
</beans>
```

In the struts2-tiles config file I define the request mapping. This mapping uses a reference to the bean created by spring. The class attribute refers to the id attribute defined in the spring bean definition.

```
    <action name="myAction_*" method="{1}" class="myAction123">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">action.request.view</result>
    </action>
```

The Action class is annotated as follows :

```
@Controller
public class MyAction {

    @Autowired
    public MyService myService;

    public MyService getMyService() {
        return myService;
    }

    public void setMyService(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    public String doSearch() {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Please find the stack trace below, thrown by struts when I remove the spring action bean reference.

```
09:10:37,852 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/gas]  - Exception starting filter struts
Action class [volumeRequestAction] not found - action - file:/C:/dev/Workspace/GAS2/_GAS2WebApp/target/_GAS2WebApp-2.0/WEB-INF/classes/struts2-tiles.xml:701:81
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:374)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:329)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:429)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:239)
at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:111)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reload(DefaultConfiguration.java:152)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:52)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:395)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:452)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:201)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:221)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3635)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:626)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:553)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:488)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Oct 5, 2012 9:10:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
```

I understand that I have not put the correct annotations in place which is the cause for this issue. Although I have tried reading about this quite a bit, I am still confused about migrating this particular part. I am unable to figure out if I will be using struts 2 annotations or spring annotations for this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what exactly is `BaseSupport`

Comment: Ignore BaseSupport. I edited the question and removed that. I have struts2 & spring set up using XML config files. I am trying to move them to spring 3 annotations. While doing so, my struts2-tiles config file uses the myAction bean created by Spring. For this ref. struts uses the class name myAction123 to map to the bean id myAction123 (changed in the question to make it more clear). Now I want to remove the action bean definition from the applicationContext file. In doing so struts throws me the exception "Action class [volumeRequestAction] not found - struts2-tiles.xml".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also need the line

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package.path" />
```

in your application-context.xml file to tell Spring where to go and look for annotations. There is nothing wrong with using the @Controller annotation.